# Let $s_n$ be convergent and suppose $\lim s_n>a$. Prove $\exists N\in\Bbb{N}$ where for every $n>N$ we have that $s_n>a$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

> Let $s_n$ be a convergent sequence, and suppose that $\lim s_n>a$. Prove that there exists a number $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n>N$ we have that $s_n>a$

Proof: Let $s_n$ be a convergent sequence with $\lim s_n=s$, and $s>a$. Since $s-a>0$ and $s_n$ is a convergent sequence, we can choose $\epsilon=s-a$ in the definition of convergence. So there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$, such that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, with $n>N$, we have,
\begin{align*}
|s_n-s|<& s-a\\
-s+a< s_n-&s< s-a\\
a< s_n<& 2s-a.
\end{align*}
Hence there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $s_n>a$.                                                        **QED**

Comment: Looks good to me.